# Erro na execução do Naïve Bayes utilizando Spark

Tags: python

Quando altero o arquivo de entrada (por default: *sample_svm_data.txt*), por outro também contendo atributos numéricos separados por espaços, ocorre o seguinte erro:

**File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/util.py", line 53, in _parse_libsvm_line
    index, value = items[1 + i].split(":")
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack**

O que pode ser?

O algoritmo em *python* está sendo executado utilizando o *Apache Spark*, tal qual este [exemplo](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/mllib-naive-bayes.html), sendo a única alteração o arquivo de entrada.

Answer (score 1):

A mensagem de erro encontrada indica que dentro da biblioteca, era esperado que um valor contivesse ":" quando não contém. 
(A mensagem não é explicita, por que realmente o código não esperava isso, mas veja a linha de código: ele faz um `.split(":")` e tenta atribuir o resultado disso a dois parâmetros do lado esquerdo. Sem o  ":", o split retorna apenas um valor)

Você pode verificar os dois arquivos e ver se em alguma das colunas os dados tem ":" no arquivo original?

Pode até ser que os dados sejam separados por ":" em vez de espaços.